# Prime candidates of the form $n^{(n^n)}+n^n+1$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, perfect-powers

Let $$\large f(n)=n^{(n^n)}+n^n+1$$

Checking $f(n)$ for $2\le n\le 100$, I noticed that $f(n)$ has a small prime factor except for $n=12,53$ and $60$

For $n=53$, I found the prime factor $7074407$ , but for $n=12$ and $n=60$, I did not find a prime factor yet. The numbers are too large to apply a primilaty test, so we need trial division.

> Do $f(12)$ and $f(60)$ have a "small" prime factor, or are those numbers candidates for very large primes ?

Comment: What happens with $6^{6^6}+6^6+1$?

Comment: $11$ is a prime divisor.

Comment: While $f(12)$ and $f(60)$ are readily shown to have no prime divisors $<10^9$, I am not convinced that it is prime.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen In fact, the numbers have a very small probability to be prime, even trial division upto $10^{100}$ or even $10^{1000}$ would not make it probable that they are prime. I only wonder whether there is a moderate prime factor, lets say, one below $10^{12}$

Comment: How are these numbers too large for primality testing?  Isn't there now a polynomial time algorithm for testing primality?  Or is the degree of the polynomial still too high for this test to work practically?

Comment: @Peter Just out of curiosity, which software or programming did you use to compute the prime factors of numbers of such large numbers and on what hardware in approximately how much run time?

Comment: @OscarLanzi $f(60)$ is definitely too large. It has about $10^{107}$ digits. $f(12)$ has "only" $$9\ 622\ 088\ 391\ 635$$ digits, so it might be barely small enough for a super computer, but the calculation would take very long indeed.

Comment: @NilotpalKantiSinha I used PARI/PG and a trick, for calculating large powers modulo a prime, which is accessible by some programs (it is the powmod-command, but in PARI/GP I had to programm the routine myself. So, I did not actually work with the numbers ($f(60)$ is far too large), but the modulo-calculation is feasible without problems.

Comment: $f(12)$ has no prime factor below $\large \color\green {10^{10}}$

Comment: Just to add a reference maybe not related/useful with your problem: Hammer, and Harrington and Jones, *On the congruence* $x^x\equiv x(\text{mod }n)$, INTEGERS: The Electronical Journal of Combinatorial Number Theory **16**, Article A74 (2016). It is a free access journal. Is not required a response of this comment, and good luck.

Comment: $f(60)$ has no prime factor below $\large \color\green {4\cdot 10^9}$

Comment: With n=12 we have $$ (11+1)^{12^{12}} + (11+1)^{12} +1 = 11 k + 3$$. 11 k +3 is linear equal to f(12) which can be a prime producer if $$ k ≠ 3 t; t,integer$$.
 Last digit of f(12) is 3 so  last digit of k is 0, that is k =10 m. With k =10 and 20 we get 113 and 223 respectively which are both primes. We can check this with higher values of k. If all or most of them are primes then f(12) is most probably a prime.
With n=60 we  have 59 k +3  the linear equal to f(60). The last digit of f(60) is also 3. Like for f(12) if all or most 59 k+3 are primes then most probably is f(60)  a prime too.

Comment: Such patterns for small primes give no evidence for larger numbers of the same form, and $f(12)$ is already gigantic. To demonstrate how low the probability is that $f(12)$ is prime : Suppose, we would be able to show that $f(12)$ has no prime factor below $10^{1000}$. Then, the probability, that $f(12)$ is prime, would still be only $1.85\cdot 10^{-10}$. So, there is a great statistical evidence that $f(12)$ is composite. Additionally, a primility test would be an enormous task and proving the primilaty would be virtually hopeless.

Comment: Far easier is to prove that $f(12)$ is composite (a non-trivial factor is sufficient). Maybe, the smallest prime factor is too large to be calculated. In this case, there is no realistic hope to decide whether $f(12)$ is prime. $f(60)$ is so large that it would be a miracle if it turned out to be prime. But in this case, there is no chance to even apply a probable-prime-test. $f(60)$ is simply much too large.